# Yandex и Chrome используют transform по-разному

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Возникла такая проблема, что transform: translate ...; работает в Chrome с выводом одной позиции, а в Yandex – с выводом совсем другой.

```css
 .slogan__polygon { /*серая фигура слева*/
  height: 90px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-92%,48%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-92%,48%);
          transform: translate(-92%,48%);
 }
```

Я знаю, что Chrome и Yandex работают на разных движках, поэтому добавил правила с префиксами, однако это не помогает. В любом случае срабатывает последняя команда для обоих браузеров(если последняя с префиксом -webkit-, то используется она, если без префиксов, то применяется правило без префиксов) Первый скриншот – Chrome, второй – Yandex [image: В Chrome]

[image: В Yandex]

Comment: Chrome и Yandex работают на одном и том же движке.

Comment: А чтобы разобраться в причине происходящего, покажите достаточно полный пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему, а не вырванный из контекста кусок стилей.

Comment: Спасибо, что порекомендовали минимизировать пример – благодаря этому я смог выявить ошибку самостоятельно

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том, что я забыл убрать у этих полос position: absolute;